# How do i make the even numbers shuffle or randomized?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to make the even numbers appear shuffled or randomized any ideas? I tried pitting it into an array but it got too complicated too fast.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>

      function printEvenNums()

      {
                var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("slut").value;
        var evenNums = "<br>Jämna nummer:<br>";

        for(i=start; i<=end; i++)
        {

          if(i % 2 == 0)
          {
            evenNums += i + "<br>";
          }
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNums;
      }

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Grisen kan programera :)</h3>
    Start: <input type="number" min="0" id="start" value="1" />
    Slut: <input type="number" id="slut" min="1" value="20" />
    <input type="button" onclick="printEvenNums()" value="Få fram jämna nummer" />
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its simple store the `evenNums` in an array instead, then shuffle it and then convert into back to string again using `.join('<br/>')`

Comment: And how exactly would i do it? I tried something similar but no success

Comment: Show us what you've tried, SwagpantS. It's easier to help, and probably better for your learning, if you give us more detail, even failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the even number at a random position of result array.

Hints:

- by `Math.random() * x` to generate a random number smaller than `x`.
- use `Math.floor()` to make the random number a integer.
- by `splice()` of array, you can insert a item into an array at the position you want.

```js
function printEvenNums() {
  var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value);
  var end = parseInt(document.getElementById("slut").value);
  var evenNums = "<br>Jämna nummer:<br>";

  var evens = [];
  for (var i=start+start%2, j=2; i<=end; i+=2, j++) {
    let posi = Math.floor(Math.random()*j);
    evens.splice(posi,0, i);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = evenNums+evens.join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Grisen kan programera :)</h3>
    Start: <input type="number" min="0" id="start" value="1" />
    Slut: <input type="number" id="slut" min="1" value="20" />
    <input type="button" onclick="printEvenNums()" value="Få fram jämna nummer" />
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this is your array of even numbers

```
var array=[2,4,6,12,8,10];
```

In addition I have created a method for generating a random number within a range. got from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Examples)

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Using the above

```
var randomArray=[];

    while(array.length>0)
    {
        var random=getRandomInt(0,array.length-1);
        randomArray.push(array[random]);
        array.splice(array.indexOf(array[random]),1);

    }
    console.log(randomArray)
```

Note : *This is a just an algorithm you could use to randomize an array. Rest you have alter it to your requirements*